# Access multiple json objects in java

Tags: java, json

I am trying to access data from Json in Java code, I have written the java code, while trying to access the "tittle" or "value" in json, I am getting only one value of "title" i.e Event 1 also when I try to access "values" using list I get data like `[{"0":"1_a","1":"1_b"}, {"0":"2_a","1":"2_b"}]`

I want to access the data from both "titles" and "values" i.e Event 2 should also be displayed. 
All the imports have been made.
Code Here

```
 public class JsonToJava {

    public void JsontoString() {

        String title;
        String jsonString = "{\"title\":\"Event 1\","
                + "\"param\":[\"1\",\"2\",\"3\",\"4\",\"5\",\"6\",\"7\"],"
                + "\"status\":true,"
                + "\"values\":[{"
                + "\"0\":{\"0\":\"1_a\",\"1\":\"1_b\"},"
                + "\"1\":{\"0\":\"2_a\",\"1\":\"2_b\"}}]"
                + ",\"$$hashKey\":\"object:3\"}"
                + ",{\"title\":\"Event 2\","
                + "\"param\":[\"1\",\"2\",\"3\",\"4\",\"Price1\",\"Price2\",\"5\",\"Status\"],"
                + "\"status\":true," + "\"values\":[{"
                + "\"0\":{\"0\":\"A_a\",\"1\":\"A_b\"},"
                + "\"1\":{\"0\":\"B_a\",\"1\":\"B_b\"}}]"
                + ",\"$$hashKey\":\"object:4\"}";

        try {
            title = new JSONObject(jsonString).getString("title");

            System.out.println(title);

            // JSONObject obj = new
            // JSONObject("{"0":{"0":"1_a","1":"1_b"},"1":{"0":"2_a","1":"2_b"}}");

            JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject(jsonString);

            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            JSONArray array = obj1.getJSONArray("values");

            String val = array.getString(0);

            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                list.add(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("0"));
                list.add(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("1"));
            }

            System.out.println(list);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        JsonToJava js = new JsonToJava();

        js.JsontoString();
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to review [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20899839/retreiving-values-from-nested-json-object)

Comment: Looks like your JSON string is not valid one. Try to view your json in any JSON view . https://addons.mozilla.org/en-Us/firefox/addon/jsonview/ you will see the problem.

Comment: I encountered array parsing problems (missing/null elements) using the [JSON.org Java parser](http://www.json.org/java/). A better alternative is the [Jackson JSON Processor](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome).

Comment: @user2476906 The [JSONLint validator](http://jsonlint.com/) may be helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code

```
public void JsontoString() {
    String jsonString = "{\"root\":[{\"title\":\"Event 1\"," + "\"param\":[\"1\",\"2\",\"3\",\"4\",\"5\",\"6\",\"7\"]," + "\"status\":true," + "\"values\":[{"
            + "\"0\":{\"0\":\"1_a\",\"1\":\"1_b\"}," + "\"1\":{\"0\":\"2_a\",\"1\":\"2_b\"}}]" + ",\"$$hashKey\":\"object:3\"}"
            + ",{\"title\":\"Event 2\"," + "\"param\":[\"1\",\"2\",\"3\",\"4\",\"Price1\",\"Price2\",\"5\",\"Status\"]," + "\"status\":true,"
            + "\"values\":[{" + "\"0\":{\"0\":\"A_a\",\"1\":\"A_b\"}," + "\"1\":{\"0\":\"B_a\",\"1\":\"B_b\"}}]" + ",\"$$hashKey\":\"object:4\"}]}";
    try {
        System.out.println(jsonString);
        JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject(jsonString);

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        JSONArray array = obj1.getJSONArray("root");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            list.add(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("title"));
        }
        System.out.println(list);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```