# How to parse JSON structured-JSON Array Object in Java

Tags: java, arrays, json, parsing

i'm trying to parse this JSON code

```
{
  "resultCode":"350",
  "message":"OK",
  "result":1,
  "data":
{
    "totalCount":"2",
    "videos":[
      {
        "videoId":"73bfedf534",
        "VideoUrl":"www.videourlexample.com",
        "title":"vbsample1",
        "description":""
      },

{
        "videoId":"73bfedf534",
        "VideoUrl":"www.videourlexample.com",
        "title":"vbsample2",
        "description":""
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I was able to parse only this.

```
"resultCode":"350",
"message":"OK",
"result":1,
```

this is the java code

```
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject)  
//return the JSON code above.
jsonParser.parse(getHTML("...httpRequest..."));

    // get a String from the JSON object
    String resultCode = (String) jsonObject.get("resultCode");
    System.out.println("[RESULTCODE] The message is: " + resultCode);


    // get a String from the JSON object
    String message = (String) jsonObject.get("message");
    System.out.println("[MESSAGE] The message is: " + message);

    // get a number from the JSON object
    long result =  (long) jsonObject.get("result");
    System.out.println("[RESULT] The resultCode is: " + result);
```

I can't parse the "data". Someone can help me?
I would like to take each value from the json array separately... like resultCode, message and result.

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retreiving values from nested JSON Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20899839/retreiving-values-from-nested-json-object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 JSONObject mainObj= new JSONObject(yourJSON);
 String resultCode= mainObj.get("resultCode");
 String message= mainObj.get("message");
 String result= mainObj.get("result");
 JSONObject dataObj = mainObj.get("data");
 JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) dataObj.get("videos");
 for (int i = 0; i <jsonArray.length(); i++) {
   JSONObject obj= jsonArray.get(i);
   String videoId=obj.get("videoId");
   String videoUrl=obj.get("VideoUrl");
   String title=obj.get("title");
   String description=obj.get("description");
    System.out.println("videoId="+videoId   +"videoUrl="+videoUrl+"title=title"+"description="+description);        
}
 System.out.println("resultCode"+resultCode+"message"+message+"result"+result);
```

Comment: I have correct your code ... adding some cast, and jsonArray.size(). And now it works.
Thank you mate

Comment: which dependency needs imported? there are multiple options available

Comment: You Need to import org.json.JSONObject and org.json.JSONArray @CristianG

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this:-

```
JSONObject dataObj = (JSONObject)dataObj .get("data");
JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) dataObj.get("videos");
for (int i = 0; i <jsonArray.length(); i++) {
   System.out.println(((JSONObject)jsonArray.get(i)).get("videoUrl"));
}
```

Currently I have just printes videoUrl, you can similarly get other attributes for videos.

Answer (score 0):

for data use:

```
int totalCount = (int) ((Map) jsonObject.get("data")).get("totalCount");

JSONArray videos = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("data")).get("videos");
```

and then parse videos JSONArray.