# Parsing JSON string in Java android

Tags: java, android, json

I want to extract elements (state,county ) from this JSON string :
I am trying to parse a JSON string in java to have the individual value printed separately. But while making the program run I get nothing.

```
    "place": [
            {
                "address": {
                    "country_code": "fr",
                    "country": "France",
                    "state": "Normandie",
                    "county": "Calvados"
                },
                "icon": "http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/images/mapicons/poi_boundary_administrative.p.20.png",
                "importance": 0.74963706049207,
                "type": "administrative",
                "class": "boundary",
                "display_name": "Calvados, Normandie, France",
                "lon": "-0.24139500722798",
                "lat": "49.09076485",
                "boundingbox": [
                    "48.7516623",
                    "49.4298653",
                    "-1.1597713",
                    "0.4466332"
                ],
                "osm_id": "7453",
                "osm_type": "relation",
                "licence": "Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright",
                "place_id": "158910871"
            }
        ]
```

any help would be appreciated. thanks.

these is my android code :

```
JSONObject objectPremium = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(result));
                        String premium = objectPremium.getString("premium");
                        JSONArray jArray1 = objectPremium.getJSONArray("premium");



                        for(int i = 0; i < jArray1.length(); i++)
                        {

                            JSONObject object3 = jArray1.getJSONObject(i);
                            adresse = object3.getJSONObject("place").getJSONObject("address").getString("state");
                            Log.e("mylog",adresse);

                        }
```

Comment: It's rather difficult to help you find problems with code that you haven't posted.

Comment: Can you share the code, How are you trying to parse a JSON string in java to have the individual value printed separately.

Comment: You need to post your Android code

Comment: @CatarinaFerreira  ok , i have updated my  post

Comment: change this line "JSONArray jArray1 = objectPremium.getJSONArray("premium");" to JSONArray jArray1 = objectPremium.getJSONArray("place");"

Comment: @ShaileshYadav,  i have updated my post

Comment: `place` is not an object - it's an array. There can be multiple `address`es, because there can be multiple `place`s. In future try to avoid one-liner code like this, and read what an exception says.

Comment: Also you only have 1 object in array.  Why are you iterating over it?

Comment: place is not a json object its a json array. first convert place into json array then iterate through it to get the json objects and required results.

Comment: you can refer the following link to get the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32522147/how-to-parse-json-structured-json-array-object-in-java/32522371#32522371

Answer (score 6):

1. In your `JSON` string, `"place"` is a `JSONArray` and its containing another `JSONObject`. Get `"place"` value as below:

   ```
   // Place
   JSONArray place = jsonObj.getJSONArray("place");
   ```
2. Get `"address"` value as below:

   ```
   // Address
   JSONObject address = place.getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("address");
   ```
3. Get `"countryCode"`, `"country"`, `"state"` and `"county"` value as below:

   ```
   String countryCode = address.getString("country_code");
   String country = address.getString("country");
   String state = address.getString("state");
   String county = address.getString("county");
   ```

**Here is the fully working code. Try this:**

```
public void parseJson() {

    // Your JOSON string
    String jsonStr = "{\"place\": [\n" +
            "            {\n" +
            "                \"address\": {\n" +
            "                    \"country_code\": \"fr\",\n" +
            "                    \"country\": \"France\",\n" +
            "                    \"state\": \"Normandie\",\n" +
            "                    \"county\": \"Calvados\"\n" +
            "                },\n" +
            "                \"icon\": \"http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/images/mapicons/poi_boundary_administrative.p.20.png\",\n" +
            "                \"importance\": 0.74963706049207,\n" +
            "                \"type\": \"administrative\",\n" +
            "                \"class\": \"boundary\",\n" +
            "                \"display_name\": \"Calvados, Normandie, France\",\n" +
            "                \"lon\": \"-0.24139500722798\",\n" +
            "                \"lat\": \"49.09076485\",\n" +
            "                \"boundingbox\": [\n" +
            "                    \"48.7516623\",\n" +
            "                    \"49.4298653\",\n" +
            "                    \"-1.1597713\",\n" +
            "                    \"0.4466332\"\n" +
            "                ],\n" +
            "                \"osm_id\": \"7453\",\n" +
            "                \"osm_type\": \"relation\",\n" +
            "                \"licence\": \"Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright\",\n" +
            "                \"place_id\": \"158910871\"\n" +
            "            }\n" +
            "        ]}";


    if (jsonStr != null) {

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

            // Place
            JSONArray place = jsonObj.getJSONArray("place");

            // Address
            JSONObject address = place.getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("address");

            String countryCode = address.getString("country_code");
            String country = address.getString("country");
            String state = address.getString("state");
            String county = address.getString("county");

            Log.d("SUCCESS", "State: " + state + " Country: " + country + " County: " + county);

        } catch (final JSONException e) {
            Log.e("FAILED", "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will help~

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need is to make sure you are receiving this string or not. I am assuming you are trying to fetch it from some URL. 
To fetch the JSON you can use the following code snippet.

```
private void getJSON(final String urlWebService) {
    class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(urlWebService);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                String json;
                while ((json = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(json + "\n");
                }
                return sb.toString().trim();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }

        }
    }
    GetJSON getJSON = new GetJSON();
    getJSON.execute();
}
```

You need to pass your URL to this function. And if calling this method is displaying the JSON data that you are expecting then the first part is done. You have the JSON string in `onPostExecute()` method.

Now you can easily parse this string if it contains a valid JSON data. But the JSON that you shown in your question does not seems a valid JSON. I guess it is only part of a big JSON file. So if you need the exact code to parse your JSON post the full JSON.

Pat parsing is very easy. If the json you have is an object create an instance of `JSONObject` if it is an array create an instance of `JSONObject`.

Then you can easily get the keys if it is an object. Or you can traverse through items if it is an array.

For more details you can check this **[JSON Parsing in Android](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/json-parsing-in-android/)** post.

Answer (score 0):

Change for this:

```
   JSONObject objectPremium = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(result));
                            String premium = objectPremium.getString("premium");
                            JSONArray jArray1 = objectPremium.getJSONArray("premium");



                            for(int i = 0; i < jArray1.length(); i++)
                            {

                                JSONObject object3 = jArray1.getJSONObject(i);
                                JSONArray placeArray = object3.getJSONArray("place")
                               JSONObject addressObject = placeArray.getJSONObject("address");

    adress = addressObject.getString("state");
                                Log.e("mylog",adresse);

                            }
```

If your initial part of the JSON Parsing code is correct, then this should work!

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

JSONObject objectPremium = jArray.get(0);

JSONObject json = jsonObject.getJSONObject("address");

String state = json.getString("state");

String country = json.getString("country");
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

Check this code,
 this is how you parse and store in a list

```
     String jsonStr = //your json string
     HashMap<String, String> addressList= new HashMap<>();

     if (jsonStr != null) {
        try {
           JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

           // Getting JSON Array node
           JSONArray address = jsonObj.getJSONArray("address"); // for the address

           // looping through All that
           for (int i = 0; i < address.length(); i++) {
              JSONObject c = address.getJSONObject(i);
              String country_code= c.getString("country_code");
              String country= c.getString("country");
              String state= c.getString("state");
              String county = c.getString("county");

              // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
              address.put("country_code", country_code);
              address.put("country", country);
              address.put("state", state);
              address.put("county", county);

              // adding address to address list
              addressList.add(address);
           }
        } catch (final JSONException e) {
           Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
           runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                 "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }
           });
    }
```