# How to get nested JSON object

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

I'm trying to get nested json object using retrofit. here is my json result

```
 {
  "results":
  {
    "sunrise":"7:27:02 AM",
    "sunset":"5:05:55 PM",
    "solar_noon":"12:16:28 PM",
    "day_length":"9:38:53",
    "civil_twilight_begin":"6:58:14 AM",
    "civil_twilight_end":"5:34:43 PM",
    "nautical_twilight_begin":"6:25:47 AM",
    "nautical_twilight_end":"6:07:10 PM",
    "astronomical_twilight_begin":"5:54:14 AM",
    "astronomical_twilight_end":"6:38:43 PM"
  },
   "status":"OK"
}
```

But I don't need all fields and only need sunrise field. How I get that sunrise field without other fields.

Comment: use this to generate model class and remove unnecessary fields:  http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: You have to make another POJO class for results and add the object using serializable name of "results"

Comment: Duplicate Question found:  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14898768/how-to-access-nested-elements-of-json-object-using-getjsonarray-method and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20899839/retreiving-values-from-nested-json-object

Answer (score 2):

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject((String) o);
String sunrise = object.getJSONObject("results").getString("sunrise");
```

Use this.Hope help you.